# cryptography not loading openssl certificate

Tags: python, python-cryptography

with that I have created an openssl key and certificate

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout test.key -out test.cert
```

with that I would like to load the certificate

```
from cryptography import x509
cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate('test.cert')
```

but failed with that exception

```
line 636, in _bytes_to_bio
data_ptr = self._ffi.from_buffer(data)
TypeError: from_buffer() cannot return the address of a unicode object
```

as far I can see I followed the documentation. How would I correctly create/use x509 certs with python >=3.8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/), `load_pem_x509_certificate` does not take a file name, but the certificate data as `bytes`.

This means you have to load the data from file first, and do so in binary mode (even though pem files contain text):

```
with open('test.cert', 'rb') as certfile:
    certbyes = certfile.read()
    cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(certbytes)
```

Comment: somehow my comment disapeared. Thanks a lot and sorry for overlooking that in the docs

Comment: @user3732793 no problem. Python's "freedom" with typing is both a strength and a weakness of the language, and I think it is natural to expect a function named `load_pem_x509_certificate` to actually load a pem file, but I guess the devs wanted to make it more generic so certs can be obtained from different sources...